# Last day of year: code valid for any timezone

Tags: javascript, date, timezone

I need to get the last day of a year in ISO format, this is, the string `2020-31-12`.

This is not as easy as one could imagine, as, the result depends in which time zone is executed.

This is the code I have. One thing must be sayed though. The commands `new Date()` and `date.toISOString(date)` are executed in different parts of the code, and the date can have different values, so it's not as simple as writing a string like `year + '-31-12'`.

```
var dateEnd   = new Date(year, 11, 31, 24, 59, 59); //This creates a date in users timezone
// [...]
$(td).html(dateEnd.toISOString().substr(0, 10)); //This converts the date to UTC, performing a transformation
```

If, as an alternative, I try:

```
var endMonth = (dateEnd.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0');
var endDay = (dateEnd.getDate()).toString().padStart(2, '0');
$(td).html(dateEnd.getFullYear() + '-' + endMonth + '-' + endDay);
```

Amazingly, it also performs a transformation, resulting in 2021-01-01 in some timezones.

Another alternative I could be using `new Date(year, 11, 31, 12, 0, 0)` which I'm not sure if it's secure enough when used in GMT+12 area.

Is there a better solution?

I did this fiddle, depending on your timezone, the result may vary.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code.

```
d = new Date();
iso_d = d.toISOString();
iso_d.split("T")[0];
```

Comment: But this is equivalent to `d.toISOString().substr(0, 10)` which I'm doing. The problem is that `new Date()` creates date in current time zone, but then it converts to UTC in `toString` or `getMonth()` etc. Thank you.

Comment: What about converting everything to UTC ??
`d = new Date();
console.log ( d.getUTCDay() +' - '+  d.getUTCMonth() + ' - ' + d.getUTCFullYear() ) ;`

Comment: That seemed to work, only one thing: `d.getUTCDay()` returns day in the week, while `d.getUTCDate()` returns day in month. If you want to write an answer I'll accept as valid.